# Strange display EOF character in the windows console

Tags: c, console, putchar

Recently faced with an interesting interpretation of the EOF character console windows. On some machines running windows 7 code `putchar (255)` && `putchar (-1)` is displayed as a space character, and some as `'a'` character. The second confuses me. Tell me please, why is this happening?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`EOF` is not a character, it's more like a signal (not the Unix signal) indicating End-of-File. Is value is implementation dependent, but guaranteed to be unequal to any valid character, usually `-1`.

When you use `putchar(EOF)`, or `putchar(-1)`, it's converted to `unsigned char`, `255`. But the ASCII value `255` isn't a printable character, the result varies in different machines.

Answer (score 2):

The actual value of `EOF` is system-dependent (but is commonly -1, such as in glibc) and is unequal to any valid character code.

Comment: I know about system-dependending EOF value, but whether to displaying of -1 code depend from compiler or console settings in windows?

Comment: The value of `EOF` is equal to any Character code. So the result can be anything in the world. So loosely speaking - yes, it may have happened due to the way your compiler has been implemented.